# Counting calls and maximum recursive depth by a decorator in python

Tags: python, recursion, decorator

I would like to have a decorator that has two fields, let's say `.ncalls` and `.rdepth`. When it wraps a function, the **ncalls** should count how many times the function called itself and **rdepth** should represent maximum recursion depth achieved, if a function is recursive.
I've tried something like here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690214/12313533) but it doesn't work.
My code now looks like a hybrid of a previously mentioned and code to count function calls with a decorator:

```
def call_counter(func): #a decorator to count calls
    def helper(x):
        helper.calls += 1
        return func(x)
    helper.calls = 0
    return helper
```

So i need something like this (this doesn't work):

```
def depthcounter(func):
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         wrapper.rdepth += 1
         wrapper.ncalls += 1
         result = func(*args, **kwargs)
         return result
     wrapper.ncalls = 0
     wrapper.rdepth = 0
     return wrapper
```

For example, let's say I have a factorial numbers producing function like

```
@depthcounter
def factorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)

#Here is some working code

print(factorial.ncalls, factorial.rdepth)
factorial(4)
print(factorial.ncalls, factorial.rdepth)
factorial(10)
print(factorial.ncalls, factorial.rdepth)
print(factorial.ncalls, factorial.rdepth)
factorial(20)
print(factorial.ncalls, factorial.rdepth)
factorial(2)
print(factorial.ncalls, factorial.rdepth)
```

And with the decorator I need it to produce this:

```
0 0
4 4
10 10
10 10
20 20
2 2
```

But I get this instead:

```
0 0
4 4
14 14
14 14
34 34
36 36
```

Comment: 4, 10, and 20. Sorry, forgot to add that. I’ve edited some code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorators are executed as soon as the module is imported, so your assignment `wrapper.ncalls = 0` is executed only once and not at every function call.
You need to keep track of starting number of counts inside of `wrapper` function. here is a working piece of code:

```
def callcounter(func):
    callcounter.ncalls  = 0
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): 
        initial_calls = callcounter.ncalls
        callcounter.ncalls += 1
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapper.ncalls = callcounter.ncalls - initial_calls
        return result
    return wrapper

@callcounter
def factorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)

factorial(4)
print(factorial.ncalls)
factorial(10)
print(factorial.ncalls)
```

Output

```
4
10
```